# Do indexes help a mysql MEMORY table?

Tags: mysql, memory, optimization

I was optimizing a 3 GB table as a MEMORY table in order to do some analysis on it, and I was curious if adding indexes even help a MEMORY table.  Since the data is all in memory anyway, is this just redundant?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, they're not redundant.

Yes, continue to use indexes.

The speed of access to a memory table on smaller tables with a non-indexed column may seem almost identical to the indexed ones due to how fast full table scans can be in memory, but as the table grows or as you join them together to make larger result sets there will be a difference.

Regardless of the storage method the engine uses (disk/memory), proper indexes will improve performance as long the storage engine supports them.  How the indexes are implemented may vary, but I know they are implemented in the table types MEMORY, INNODB, and MyISAM.  BTW: The default method for indexes in MEMORY tables is with a hash instead of a B-Tree.

Also, I generally don't recommend coding to your storage engine.  What's a memory table today may need to changed to innodb tomorrow--the SQL and schema should stand on it's own.

Comment: Well it looks like mysql (8) devs agree (wrongfully) and just ignore the indexes in memory tables 99% of the time.
I've a great real world example: I try to get an INT column within a time range of 3 seconds (a couple hundred rows to scan by index). 
Well mysql does a fulltable scan on millions of rows even when I use 'force index' resulting in a 150ms delay on a query that should take 1/1000 of that time.

Mysql is full of those bugs, I don't think those are accidents. It's intentional behavior from Oracle.

Answer (score 4):

No, indexing has little to do with data access speed. An index reorganizes data in order to optimize specific queries.

For example if you add a balanced binary tree index to a one-million-row column, you will be able to find the item you want in about 20 read operations, instead of a average half million.

So placing that million rows in memory, which is 100x faster than the disk, will speed a brute force search by 100x. Adding the index will *further* improve the speed by a factor of twenty-five thousand by allowing the DB to perform a *smarter* search instead of a merely *faster* search.

Things are more complicated than this, because other factors get into play, and you rarely get such large a benefit from an index. Smarter searches are also *slower* on a one-by-one basis: those 20 index seeks cost much more than 20 brute force seeks. Then there's index maintenance, etc.

But my suggestion is to keep the data in memory if you can -- and index them.

Comment: in memory tables mysql ignores most indexes. It won't use the btree, even if it is perfectly tailored to the query and improves performance by a thousand times.